# Syntax Error on def drawPieces(screen, board):

Tags: python, import, syntax, python-3.7, importerror

Just for context - I have imported pygame into pycharm and am receiving an error on the **def** on

```
def drawPieces(screen,board):
```

The end goal is to build a chess engine but so far it's only been importing things and trying to set up something that looks like a chessboard/chess set. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnYui0e73Rs&t

Here is the rest of the code:

```
"""
This is our main driver file. It will be responsible for handling user input and displaying the current GameState object
"""
#import os
#import sys
#os.chdir(sys.path[0])
# thank adam ^^^^
import pygame as p
from Chess import ChessEngine

WIDTH = HEIGHT = 400
# CAN CHANGE TO 512
DIMENSION = 8
# Dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_Size = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 15  # for animations later on
IMAGES = {}

'''
Initialize a global dictionary of images. This will be called once in the main 
'''


def loadImages():
    # could do "IMAGES['wp'] = p.image.load("images/wp.png")"
    # this for all 16 pieces but would be very redundant
    # do the following instead
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wQ', 'wK', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bQ', 'bK']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_Size, SQ_Size))
    # Note: we can access an image by saying 'IMAGES['wp']'


'''
The main driver for our code. This will handle user input and updating the graphics
'''


def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    # clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = ChessEngine.GameState()
    # initializes GameState (in Chess Engine.py) - initialize construction of pieces and creates the 3 variables
    print(gs.board)
    loadImages() # only do this once, b4 the while loop
    running = True
    while running:
        for e in p.eve.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            drawGameState(screen, gs)
            clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
            p.display.flip()

'''
Responsible for all graphics within a current game state
'''
def drawGameState(screen, gs):
    drawBoard(screen) #draws squares on board
    #add in piece highlighting or move suggestions
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)  # draw pieces on top of the squares
    # order matters here - draw board before pieces. If you draw them the other way - creates board on top of pieces
    # - you wont see pieces
'''
Draw the square on the board.
'''
'''
Top left square on a board is always light
'''
def drawBoard(screen):
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("grey")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.React(c*SQ_Size, r*SQ_Size, SQ_Size, SQ_Size)

# Draw the pieces on the board using the current GameState.board

def drawPieces(screen, board):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

and if you need to reference ChessEngine (as it is referenced in the code) - here it is:

```
"""
This class is responsible for storing all the information about the current state ofa chess game. It will also be
responsible for determining the valid moves at the current state. It will also keep a move log.
"""


class GameState:
    # may want to add parenthesis after State^^
    def __init__(self):
        # Board is an 8x8 2d list, each element of the list has 2 characters
        # The first characters represents the color of peice, 'b' or 'w'
        # The second characters represents the type of the piece, 'K', 'Q'. 'R', 'B', 'N', or'P'
        # "--"- represents an empty space
        self.board = [
            ["br", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wr", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]]
        self.whiteToMove = True
        self.moveLog = []
```

It is worth mentioning that I am only beginning to learn python. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check the previous line. You've probably got a missing parenthesis or something. Perhaps a commented-out function body that doesn't count as a body.

Comment: You're missing a `)` in the `p.draw.rect` line.

Comment: Yep, that's a missing parenthesis.